# NetworkX community detection algorithms run indefinetely

Tags: python, networkx, social-networking

I am using NetworkX library for its community detection algorithms.Currently I am working with the [Pokec](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-pokec.html) dataset from SNAP datasets. I keep the largest Strongly Connected Component in order to work with.

Unfortunately every community detection algorithm takes indefinetely execution time for the specific dataset. Specifically, I let Girvan Newman run overnight and about 12 hours of execution later, the algorithm still running. Currently, I am running Greedy Modularity and after 400mins still no result.

I am following documentation instructions but yet I am feeling that it is not optimal for large graphs like this one.

Has anyone else addressed something like that? Am I using the library in wrong way for large datasets? Should I be more patient and wait more for results?

My code is underneath:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.community import greedy_modularity_communities

pokec = nx.read_edgelist("Data/soc-pokec-relationships.txt", nodetype=int, delimiter='\t', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

pokecSCC = max(nx.strongly_connected_components(pokec), key=len)
pokecSCCGraph = pokec.subgraph(pokecSCC)

modularity_comms = greedy_modularity_communities(pokecSCCGraph)
```

Comment: using networkx on huge graphs is usually a bad idea

Comment: @RiccardoBucco any alternative suggestion?

Comment: Try the igraph package (if you are limited to python), from my experience it is faster than networkx